# how to securely use LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm building a script where users can search a database. my understanding is that PDO doesn't let you set a parameter for the LIKE operand. So I have this code to make up for it

```
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%" . $this->sQuery . "%' LIMIT 30";
$Statement = $this->Database->prepare($sQuery);
$Statement->execute();
```

I doubt this is secure against SQL injection. Is there any way to make it secure?

Comment: You can use `like` with PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, interpolating any value into an SQL string creates a risk for SQL injection vulnerability.  It's better to use a SQL query parameter placeholder when you `prepare()`, and then supply the value as a parameter when you `execute()`.

```
$pattern = "%" . $this->sQuery . "%";
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ? LIMIT 30";
$Statement = $this->Database->prepare($sQuery);
$Statement->execute(array($pattern));
```

Take that as pseudocode because I can't tell from your example which MySQL extension you're using.  I'm assuming PDO, which allows parameters to be sent as an array argument to `execute()`.

Some people use `PDOStatement::bindParam()`, but there's no advantage to doing so.  Maybe in some other RDBMS brands the `PDO::PARAM_STR` matters, but in the MySQL driver, the parameter type is ignored.

PS: Aside from the security issue you asked about, you will find a search for wildcard-based patterns like you're doing don't perform well as your data grows larger.  See my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Comment: oh okay I see. When I tried placing the parameter inside the sql code I had it like "WHERE column LIKE %?%;" and that didn't work. But this got the job done. Thank you. And yes it was pdo.

Comment: The % characters must be part of the string, but a ? placeholder must *not* be inside string delimiters.  So the best way is to concatenate the wildcards with the pattern, and use that whole string as the parameter value.

Comment: thanks for the presentation too. definitely something i'll need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$sQuery    = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE :query LIMIT 30";
$Statement = $this->Database->prepare($sQuery);
$Statement->execute(array(':query' => '%' . $this->sQuery . '%'));
```